# python Flask-oauth with facebook is throwing a webpage not found error

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, flask

I am trying to authenticate my user using facebook oauth but it is throwing a webpage not found error after the user allows my app in facebook.

Here's the code:

```
from flask import redirect, Flask, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'asd'

oauth = OAuth()
facebook = oauth.remote_app('facebook',
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    consumer_key='xxx',
    consumer_secret='yyy',
    request_token_params={'scope': 'email'}
)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    print(url_for('oauth_authorized'))
    return facebook.authorize(callback='www.resoorce.com' + url_for('oauth_authorized'))

@app.route('/oauth_authorized')
@facebook.authorized_handler
def oauth_authorized(resp):
    print("asd")
    if resp is None:
        print(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
        return "NOOOO"



    print('You were signed in as %s' % resp['screen_name'])
    return "YEAH!!!"


if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.debug = True;
    app.run(hostname = '0.0.0.0', port=int(80))
```

No error was thrown anywhere, just webpage not found.

Comment: try `return facebook.authorize('http://your call back url')`

Comment: tried it just now.. Didn't work. Same no webpage found error

Comment: can you post your callback url ?

Comment: callback is http://www.resoorce.com/oauth_authorized after authentication facebook is calling back the same function with a code parameter. ie., it is adding ?code=adsfasdfsdaf..... to the end of the url.

Comment: Since it is adding that code parameter to the url I tried changing the oauth_authorized function to accept a code parameter but it is still not working.

Comment: call back url shoulbe same as set in facebook app

Comment: facebook app? Did you mean facebook developer page' setting? I tried locating a callback setting there but couldn't find anything

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/ . create app and add settings there

Comment: ofcourse I created an app there, how do you think I got my consumer_key and consumer_secret? The only setting related to oauth it has is this form where I could register a callback function and I did, before I posted this question.

Comment: What address is shown in the browser address bar when you get that not found error?

Comment: resoorce.com/oauth_authorized?code=some_random_geberish

Comment: On accessing your url, I get the following error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. You might need to fix this first.